# fazer upload de várias imagens ao mesmo tempo para alimentar um slide

Tags: php

Estou neste momento a tentar fazer é upload de varias imagens ao mesmo tempo para a tabela imagens, estas tem que ser armazenas todas juntas ou seja dentro de um array certo? de maneira a ficarem assim (http://gyazo.com/237d0e2107dcd90c388b139c64a6b4a6), o meu problema é que o codigo que tenho faz me como se tivesse a inserir uma a uma para aparecerem no site assim:(http://gyazo.com/81566817c75b802e670352031ecbc00b) basicamente o que quero é dentro da tabela imagem armazenar uma imagem que contem várias imagens para alimentar um slide.

```
$fdata = $_FILES['img'];
    $uploads_dir = '/upload';
    //echo count($fdata['name']);
    for($i = 0; $i < count($fdata['name']); ++$i)
    {

  $data=date("ymd");
  $query=("insert into `portfolio_imagens` (`nome`, `descricao`,`cliente`,`imagem`,`publicacao`) VALUES ('".$_POST['nome']."','".$_POST['descricao']."','".$_POST['cliente']."','".$name."','".$data."')");   $result=mysql_query($query);
        $name = $_FILES['img']['name'][$i];
        $temp_name = $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'][$i];
        move_uploaded_file($temp_name, "$uploads_dir"."$name");
    }
```

Comment: Não percebi o problema.

Comment: eu quero adicionar projetos em que cada projeto tem as imagens correspondentes, depois no site na pagina inicial aparece a imagem principal do projeto e quando clico nela manda me para projetos.php onde tem a informação do projeto e um carousel a passar as imagens que introduzi, mas o que eu preciso é de adicionar as imagens em cada projeto.

Comment: primerito projeto add-->tabela imagens--> introduzi um conjunto de imagens-->imagem1.png,imagem2.png,imagem3.png

Answer (score 2):

Você deve deixar o SQL fora do loop e dentro dele fazer o upload das imagens e armazenar os nomes num array para inserir no banco depois:

```
$fdata = $_FILES['img'];
$uploads_dir = '/upload';
$img = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($fdata['name']); $i++) {
    $name = $_FILES['img']['name'][$i];
    $temp_name = $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'][$i];
    move_uploaded_file($temp_name, "$uploads_dir"."$name");
    $img[] = $name;
}
$data = date("ymd");
$img = implode(';', $img);
$query = "INSERT INTO `portfolio_imagens` (`nome`, `descricao`,`cliente`,`imagem`,`publicacao`) VALUES ('".$_POST['nome']."', '".$_POST['descricao']."', '".$_POST['cliente']."', '".$img."', '".$data."')";
mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: Lucas muito obrigado funcionou :O agradeço mesmo nem sabe as voltas que andei com isto, diga me mais uma coisa, agora o codigo que tenho para ir buscar as imagens para serem apresentadas no slide nao deve de estar a funcionar pode dar uma olhadela? http://pastebin.com/eqq9q1rY agradeço

Comment: Altere o primeiro parâmetro do `explode` para um ";" (ponto-e-vírgula)

Comment: sim acabei mesmo de fazer isso, mas tenho um problema, por exemplo de 5 imagens que faço upload so 2/3 aparecem, nunca aparecem todas

Comment: Verifique se as imagens foram salvas e se está tudo certinho no banco.

Comment: no banco de dados estao todas as imagens mas na pasta so algumas, nao estao todas as que introduzi

Comment: Lucas ja resolvi o problema, o ";" estava a dar erro tive que meter "," mas agora tenho outro problema será que me poderia ajudar?

Comment: Se você alterou no explode, tem que alterar no implode também e vice-versa.

Comment: sim isso ja esta feito, o meu problema é o seguinte : no index agora terei que mostrar uma imagem do array que escolhi ser a primira, para assim quando se clicar na imagem ir para a pagina projetos.php onde tem a informação e o slide a passar as imagens, mas o codigo que tenho so me mostra uma imagem adicionada ou seja add 2 imagens http://gyazo.com/380da2fab2c790df93c4587ed37bab31 e no site so me mostrou 1 http://gyazo.com/ecf6e19fa456e0e5f984f64580d46265 o cogido esta aqui http://pastebin.com/pyd1p6iD

Comment: Nesse código você está pegando apenas a primeira imagem (índice 0 do array). Se você quer exibir todas, faça um loop em $imagem_arry.

Answer (score 0):

```
$images = $_FILES['img'];

$uploads_dir = '/upload';

$img = array();

foreach($images as $image)
{
  $name = $image['name'];
  $temp_name = $image['tmp_name'];
  if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, "$uploads_dir.$name"))
  {
    //O arquivo foi movido para o destino com sucesso.
    // Você não vai querer registrar o nome de uma imagem que não existe na pasta uploads
    $img[] = $name;
  }
}

$date = date("Ymd");

$img = implode(';', $img);

$query = "INSERT INTO `portfolio_imagens` (`nome`, `descricao`,`cliente`,`imagem`,`publicacao`) VALUES ('".$_POST['nome']."', '".$_POST['descricao']."', '".$_POST['cliente']."', '".$img."', '".$date."')";

mysql_query($query);
```

Pelo que percebi, o atributo imagem da tabela portfolio_imagens é um atributo multivalorado.

Apenas uma dica: Não use a extensão mysql do php. No lugar utilize mysqli ou pdo_mysql.
mysql é antiga e possui uma série de falhas de segurança;
Para trocar mysql por mysql, apenas acrescente o 'i', pois a maioria das funções possuem o mesmo nome, com o acrescimo do 'i'.

Comment: ja consegui obrigado :)

Comment: Recomendo filtar o nome dos arquivos e substituir caracteres especiais: à ou á po a, espaços por _ ou -, etc.